# Does Android MediaPlayer support HTTP Partial Content

Tags: android, http

I have an android app which plays audio from server by http streaming. Server supports range headers and provides response based on range requests.

Can android media player request with range header , like chrome player does?

We can use SetDataSource for adding header parameters - but is there any way to get current byte position , which mediaplayer is playing or how can we do current time to byte calculation

Thanks

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?